# Select a cell in a datagridview and start editing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, cell

I see on the internet that the topic is very common, and I do not understand why has not been created a method for direct selection of a cell in a datagridview.

I created this class Helper:

```
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace gestione_magazzino_v4.Classi
{
    static class DataGridViewHelper
    {
        static public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dg, int row, int column)
        {
            DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dg, row);

            if (rowContainer != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);  

                DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);  // <<<------ ERROR
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
                    dg.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dg.Columns[column]);
                    cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                }
                return cell;
            }
            return null;
        }

        static public DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid dg, int index)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
            if (row == null)
            {
                // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
                dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[index]);
                row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
            }
            return row;
        }

        static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        }
    }
}
```

I use this code like this:

```
DataGridCell cell = DataGridViewHelper.GetCell(datagridview, 0, 2);
if (cell != null)
    cell.Focus();
```

But I get an error where I highlighted, in particular, I get **System.NullReferenceException**

I do not understand what is missing ... On the net there are many examples, but they are all identical to what I did, and I do not understand what's missing!

Comment: Can you check with debugger attached that `presenter` is null?

Comment: Yes...`presenter` si null...Is `GetVisualChild` that return always null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foud solution!!!
The problem was to use:

```
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

**But the correct one is:**

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

Answer (score 1):

The DataGridCellPresenter is null , this occurs due to the DataGrid's Virtualization.

Lets say you have 100 rows and you scroll down to row [49] where that row is the top most visible row on the screen , for rows 0-48 , their DataGridCellPresenter was Virtualized (disposed).

```
DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);  
if(presenter != null)
{
    // Select your cell...
}
```

This is in case you are selecting it after scrolling ,another example for this scenario might be when you try to do so when your UserControl (or any form of view) is first shown.

You must wait for the DataGrid to load :

```
 dataGrid.Loaded += DG_Loaded;


 void DG_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        ScrollViewer _sv = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(dataGrid);           
 }
```

Before the DataGrid finished loading all it's VisualTree was not yet created including it's top most child The ScrollViewer shown above.

Replace your GetVisualChild with this :

```
 public static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : Visual
 {
      if (depObj != null)
      {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in GetVisualChild<T>(child))
                {
                    return childOfChild;
                }
            }
       }
       return null;
  }
```

What i think is wrong is that not all the elements on your way down the visual tree are Visual's , 
for instance any panel along the way is not a Visual, so when you cast it to Visual you get null and never reach the DataGridCellPresenter .

Comment: at what point are you attempting to Get the cell , was the DataGrid already created and then you send it to the helper ? 
or is it in a constructor or a callback of a Dependency Property 
post where you call DataGridViewHelper.GetCell(datagridview, 0, 2);

Comment: After the interface has been fully charged and after load the data (2 rows). 
By clicking a button
`DataGridCell cell = DataGridViewHelper.GetCell(datagridview, 0, 2);`

Comment: o'k so my answer is irreverent , i'll think about it some more.